# MySQL query Sum and Substract

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to sum the rows when E1_CHECK is true between 2 dates ill try my best to explain here is my table from this code

```
select e.e1_fecha2,a.a1_nombre,a.A1_NUMCUENTA,f.CF_KIT,e.E1_CC,e.E1_MONTo,f.CF_NUM,f.CF_MONTO
from
e1 as e inner join cf as f on e.CF_num=f.CF_num
inner join a1 as a on f.a1_ID=a.a1_id
where
e.E1_CHECK=true and E1_FECHA2 between '2016-02-01' and '2016-02-29'
```

and it shows this

```
 e1_fecha2 | a1_nombre | A1_NUMCUENTA | CF_KIT    | E1_CC | E1_Monto | CF_NUM        |CF_Monto
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2016-02-29|khaldun    |123456        | 55        |1/5    |1320000   |001-001-0000002|6600000
 2016-02-29|khaldun    |123456        |8 cameras  |1/5    |1100000   |001-001-0000003|5500000 
 2016-02-29|khaldun    |123456        |8 cameras  |2/5    |1100000   |001-001-0000003|5500000
 2016-02-29|oiuiouio   |64            | fff       |1/1    |1375000   |001-001-0000004|1375000 
 2016-02-29|khaldun    |123456        | 44444     |1/1    |5500000   |444-444-4422222|5500000
 2016-02-29|khaldun    |123456        |rrrr       |1/1    |1125000   |001-001-0000006|1125000
```

and `E1_Monto` is part of the payment and `CF_MONTO` is the total bill what i want is to substract `CF_Monto - E1_MONTO` and how much left to pay for example

this is how i want it to look like

```
 e1_fecha2 | a1_nombre | A1_NUMCUENTA | CF_KIT    | E1_CC | E1_Monto | CF_NUM        | CF_Monto  | Payed     | Left_to_Pay 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2016-02-29|khaldun    |123456        | 55        |1/5    |1320000   |001-001-0000002| 6600000   |1320000    |5280000
 2016-02-29|khaldun    |123456        |8 cameras  |1/5    |1100000   |001-001-0000003| 5500000   |1100000    |4400000
 2016-02-29|khaldun    |123456        |8 cameras  |2/5    |1100000   |001-001-0000003| 5500000   |2200000    |3300000
 2016-02-29|oiuiouio   |64            | fff       |1/1    |1375000   |001-001-0000004| 1375000   |1375000    |0
 2016-02-29|khaldun    |123456        | 44444     |1/1    |5500000   |444-444-4422222| 5500000   |5500000    |0
 2016-02-29|khaldun    |123456        |rrrr       |1/1    |1125000   |001-001-0000006| 1125000   |1125000    |0
```

i tried other ways but it only shows 1 row and sum all togather.

Answer (score 1):

Just select the columns and do the operation(subtract). I have changed

`SELECT *, E1_MONTO AS payed,CF_Monto - E1_MONTO AS left_to_pay` this line. Hope it helps.

```
SELECT *, E1_MONTO  AS payed,CF_Monto - E1_MONTO AS left_to_pay
FROM e1 AS e INNER JOIN cf AS f ON e.CF_num=f.CF_num
INNER JOIN a1 AS a ON f.a1_ID=a.a1_id
WHERE
e.E1_CHECK=true AND E1_FECHA2 BETWEEN '2016-02-01' AND '2016-02-29'
```

Comment: and the payed column ? check row 2 and 3

Comment: see my select statement.

Comment: By this you will get extra two columns as payed and left_to_pay which I hope you desired.

Comment: Kindly ask if some problem still pertains. Thanks

Comment: well after using that code iam getting this result
    the row 2 and 3 payed column arent suming as on the example and when substract row 2 and 3 they have same CF_NUM they should be 4400000 and the row 3 should be 3300000 but using this code both row give the same result as 4400000 and payed too

Answer (score 0):

i figured out how to do it this is how i did

```
select
e.e1_fecha2,e.e1_check, a.a1_nombre,a.A1_NUMCUENTA,f.CF_KIT,e.E1_CC,e.E1_MONTo, 
(select sum(IF(t.E1_CHECK = true, t.e1_monto , 0)) from e1 as t where e.CF_NUM=t.cf_num ) as payed,
CF_Monto - (select sum(IF(t.E1_CHECK = true, t.e1_monto , 0)) from e1 as t where e.CF_NUM=t.cf_num )AS left_to_pay
from e1 as e
inner join cf as f on e.CF_num=f.CF_num
inner join a1 as a on f.a1_ID=a.a1_id
where 
e.E1_CHECK=true and E1_FECHA2 between '2016-02-01' and '2016-02-29'
```

thanks everyone for the help :)